# jquery timer implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

All,

Is there a jQuery timer which can start a timer for 20 minutes and display time elapsed? Please point me to a small code for it.

```
var austDay = new getTime();
austDay = new getSeconds(austDay);
var duration = 1200;
duration +=  austDay;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about a jQuery solution, but it's quite simple to do anyway:

```
var elapsed = 0;
var interval;
var total = 60 * 20; // 20 mins in seconds

function showElapsedTime()
{
    if(elapsed < total)
    {
        elapsed += 1;

        // If you want you can convert the seconds elapsed to minutes and seconds
        // here before you display them

        $('#elapsed').html(elapsed);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert('Done');
    }
}

$(function(){
    interval = setInterval(showElapsedTime, 1000);
});
```

Where `#elapsed` is a `div` or `span` element that you want to show the elapsed time in.

There are [quite a few](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) [timer](http://www.evanbot.com/article/jquery-timer-plugin/23) [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Timer), but they are all just abstractions of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` anyway, and I'm not sure they're really much simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the [jQuery Timers](https://github.com/blairmitchelmore/jquery.plugins/blob/master/jquery.timers.js) plugin. You can change it to suit your needs.

```
$("#start").click(function() {
    $("#example_2").everyTime(1000, 'timer2', function(i) {
        $(this).text(i);
    }, 15);
});

$("#stop").click(function() {
    $("#example_2").stopTime('timer2');
});
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that those functions are part of the Timers plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers), and won't work unless you include it.

Comment: Yep, sorry. They are really required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for a plugin like [timeX](http://www.lampcoder.com/timex-jquery-plugin-fancy-auto-updating-time-to-string/)?

Maybe this is what you can use..