# javascript or jquery countdown action updating mysql table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, countdown

Is it possible to set a timer of, lets say, 30 seconds and when it reaches 0 update a `mysql` table and refresh the page?

I'm working on a game and I would like to have a variable which is 1 when the timer starts and back to 0 when it stops the countdown. I'd like to display those seconds on screen as well.

I'm currently working with html, php, mysql and css

Comment: There are plenty sources on the Internet about implementing timers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400227/jquery-timer-implementation for example. Yes, it's all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by getting a time (in seconds), converting it to Minutes:Seconds for user display countdown, then once it reaches 0, the Javascript does an ajax call to a PHP script that will then update what I need in the db.

Then I repeat as needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have this counter:
`code`<script type="text/javascript">
 var days=0,hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=180;
 
var container = document.getElementById("cr_countdown");

function countdown(){
  if(seconds == 0){
      seconds = 0;
       minutes--;
     }else{
   seconds--;
     }
     if(minutes == -1){
   minutes = 0;
      hours--;
      }
      if(hours == -1){
       days--;
  }
    container.innerHTML = seconds;
    setTimeout(countdown,1000);
    
    }

countdown();
</script>

The <div id="cr_countdown"></div> shows the time running..
How can I make an update to the database at the start & end

Comment: of the timer?
I mean.. One update as soon it starts and another when it finishes...